# Project development: control of a DC motor

Tags: dc-motor, control

Is it feasible to control a DC motor as it is described in the following picture?

[image]

What would be a possible application of this circuit? It is kind of tricky because the operational amplifier's current is feeding this machine, so I will either need a high power OpAmp or a low power DC motor, but I can't see a real life application of the latter.

Comment: It's an amplifier, that does not necessarily mean an operation amplifier.

Comment: I believe it is more common to use some type of switching control. For example a half-bridge or H-bridge. What you show strikes me as more of a conceptual diagram to aid in understanding rather than a complete circuit.

Comment: BTW; it looks like it might be a constant torque controller.

Comment: Yes. Find other diagrams. This one is not helpful. If it was really an op amp, that would burn instantly. And all these resistors don't make much sens without additional information.

Comment: This was taken from a university textbook, it is not clear what this diagram means. Could it be a power amplifier?

Comment: The big idea in this diagram is that it implements blended control of both voltage and current.

Comment: Yes it could be a power amplifier, it could also be a whole motor driver subsystem in a black-box that acts like an amplifier. The DELTA symbol is really a generic block for an amplifier, what's actually inside could be pretty much anything as long as it behaves like an amplifier between the two inputs and the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circuit is an analog regulator used to regulate DC motor speed. The amplifier is essentially a power amplifier like a power operational amplifier. It would usually be implemented using a controlled rectifier or pulse width modulation scheme.

A DC motor is basically controlled by controlling the armature terminal voltage. However regulating armature voltage does not exactly regulate the speed. Speed is proportional to the motor's counter emf. Counter EMF is less than the terminal voltage by the amount of voltage drop across the armature resistance (IR drop). That is proportional to the armature current which is proportional to torque.

To prevent the motor speed from dropping when the torque increases, it is necessary tor provide additional feedback proportional to the IR drop. That is called IR compensation. The Rs in the diagram is a shunt resistor that provides IR compensation feedback.

The amplifier should have some kind of current limiting circuit provided internally to limit the maximum current supplied during acceleration or mechanical overload.